# Using "If" and "and" in a statement

Tags: american-english, conjunctions

Which of these statements is/are correct?
This is what I am trying to convey.

> I will come to your place only if there is no rain. I will come to your place only if I have an umbrella as well.

How do I combine these two sentences with "AND"

- 1. I will only come to your place if there is no rain and I have an umbrella.
- 2. I will only come to your place if there is no rain and if I have an umbrella.
- 3. I will only come to your place if there is no rain and have an umbrella.
- 4. I will only come to your place if there is no rain and I have an umbrella.
- 5. I will only come to your place if there is no rain, and I have an umbrella.
- 6. I will only come to your place if there is no rain, and have an umbrella.
- 7. I will come to your place only if there is no rain and I have an umbrella.
- 8. I will come to your place only if there is no rain, and have an umbrella.
- 9. I will come to your place only if there is no rain and have an umbrella.

Comment: It helps if you number your sentences! The ones without 'I' before 'have' are incorrect. All the others are acceptable, though strictly speaking "I will come... only if..." is more correct.

Comment: There are too many different things in your sentences. *Have* must have a subject, and there is no suitable subject in the rest of the sentence, so all sentences with *and have* are wrong. The comma introduces an ambiguity, separating a phrase which should be part of the *if...* clause, so that ought to go too. These would reduce the number of candidate sentences considerably and make the question more manageable.

Comment: These are very strange sentences. Why would an umbrella matter if there is no rain?

Comment: @Steve, I should have chosen a better example sentence. For the sake of answering your question, the subject is worried that it may rain when he comes back home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand the question, it seeks the equivalent, in a form that fits the tone of everyday communications, of what would, in a more formal way (say, in something like a legal document) be expressed by:

> I will come to your place only if the following two conditions are both satisfied: (a) there is no rain, and (b) I have an umbrella.

The answer is **(7)**. In the first six sentences, *only* qualifies *come to your place*, rather than, as is presumably intended, the connection between coming to your place and the two conditions. The first six sentences, taken at face value, convey the idea that, under certain conditions I will come to your place and not do anything more or anything else. The third and the sixth sentence, in addition to that, have the same problem as the last two.

The last two sentences are problematic because they leave one wondering what the subject of *have an umbrella* is. It is reasonable to assume that it is *I*, but it is better to make that explicit, as (7) does.

Although (7) would be the correct answer if something like this appeared as a question on an introduction-to-logic exam, it should also be said that, in casual conversations, people are often not very attentive to such matters as the placement of *only* and the meaning of *only if*, so it is quite possible that 'in the wild' one would sometimes encounter some of the other sentences listed here, used with the intention of conveying this meaning.

(Incidentally, the example used in the question is somewhat confusing: why would one need an umbrella, if one expects that there will be no rain? This answer ignores that infelicity, and focuses, as the question presumably intends, on the logical relationships among the components of these sentences.)

Comment: You may be technically correct about what "only" modifies in the first 6 sentences, but it's very common and acceptable to shift "only" like this in cases where the literal interpretation is unlikely. People have no problem recognizing this.

Comment: E.g. if you say "I can only go to the store on Thursday", everyone understands it to mean "I can go to the store only on Thursday", not "On Thursday, the only thing I can do is go to the store."

Comment: @Barmar, yes, isn't that precisely what the next-to-last paragraph of the answer says?

Comment: Sorry, missed that part of the answer. Although I think it's more common than you suggest -- I'd guess that almost everyone would prefer #1 over #7.